# How to detect shift down when clicking on ScriptUI button?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

On my scriptUI panel, I have a button.  How can I detect whether the user is holding the `shift` key when they click on the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an eventListener to your button.

```
var win = new Window ("dialog");
win.aButton = win.add ("button", undefined, "Button");
win.aButton.addEventListener ("click", function (k) {
      if (k.shiftKey) {
        alert("foo");
      }else{
        alert("bah");
      }
  });
win.show ();
```

Comment: That, indeed, works, but I need to attach the listener to a button (I have several buttons; each needs a listener of its own).

If I do: `whatbutton.onClick = function(k){  }` it all works until I do something with `k`.

Comment: Never mind; I used your `addEventListener` instead of my `onClick` and it worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you know Peter Kahrels Script UI guide? http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html it's my favorite UI development resource

Comment: Yes, I've been there.  There is also jongware's guide: http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/