# ExtendScript - Can you listen for/change keypress behavior?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator, extendscript, photoshop-script, jsx

I can imagine a lot of different angles to this, but here is my goal:

> When I use the `[blob brush]` tool in `[Illustrator]` I want the `option` key to toggle the eyedropper tool.

I figure the specific tool and application are irrelevant, and the root of it is the ExtendScript question:

1. Can we bind actions to `keydown` and `keyup` events?
2. Can we know what tool is currently active?
3. Can we change the active tool?
4. Can we override a default keypress behavior?*

According to the internet, ExtendScript can at least do #2 (see `getCurrentTool` [**here**](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3512263)). Do you know if it can do 1, 3, and 4? Or do you have suggestions for another approach?

---

<sup>Yes, yes, another approach would be to just deal with it like everyone else. But I really want to fix this, and so do [other](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3512263) [right-thinking people](http://support.muse.adobe.com/message/5017635), and so would you if you came to Illustrator from Photoshop. You would be dumbfounded that it doesn't work this way by default. *And we are here because we don't accept what we think we can change.*</sup>

<sub>(I'm sure there are also other uses for this info.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to listen for shift+click or ctrl+click if you want to add your listener to a mouse click - [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445984/how-to-detect-right-click-on-script-ui-button), and [here, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446076/how-to-detect-shift-down-when-clicking-on-scriptui-button).

YES - [you CAN change the active tool](https://indisnip.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/change-active-tool-with-script/).

[Check out kahrel's guide to scriptUI](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html).  [The pdf file](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui-2-0.pdf) has a setion called "Listening to the Keyboard"

I'm not sure if you can override a default keypress behaviour - but you could set a new hotkey in the keyboard settings - and probably do that with a script.